# Calling activity to another activity using intent failed

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a class called "Datetime", I want to call Datetime's activity into my MainActivity using intent.

This is what I did

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Datetime.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

}

and I also updated my manifest:

```
 <activity
              android:name=".Datetime" >
 </activity>
```

but it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

Just in case, you want to refer. The following is my Datetime class:

```
public class Datetime extends Activity {

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 2;

    private Button pickDate;
    private int year, month, day;

    private Button pickTime;
    private int hours, min;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_layout);


        pickDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.date_button);

        pickDate.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }

        });

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        updateDate();


        pickTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.time_button);

        pickTime.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener () {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });

        hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        updateTime();
    }

    private void updateTime() {
        pickTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':')
                .append(min));

    }

    private void updateDate() {
        pickDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append('-')
                .append(month + 1).append('-').append(year));

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener = 
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                year = yr;
                month = monthOfYear;
                day = dayOfMonth;
                updateDate();
            }
    };

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeListener = 
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                hours = hourOfDay;
                min = minute;
                updateTime();
            }

    };
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch(id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, dateListener, year, month, day);
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, timeListener, hours, min, false);
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

logcat:

```
07-03 16:36:37.394: E/Dynamiclayout(1282): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
07-03 16:36:37.394: E/Dynamiclayout(1282): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
07-03 16:36:37.424: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1282): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-03 16:36:37.424: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1282): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-03 16:36:37.424: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1282): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-03 16:36:37.424: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1282): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
07-03 16:36:42.189: D/GestureDetector(1282): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
```

As requested, my MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity { 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ViewTab.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("View").setIndicator("View",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_view))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CreateTab.class);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Create").setIndicator("Create",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_create))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);



        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_about:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,About.class));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, Datetime.class);
        startActivity(i);


        }


}
```

Comment: have you declared Datetime in the Manfiest?

Comment: yes, I've declared. Please see my logcat too. Thanks.

Comment: Please paste your full logcat

Comment: @EtAndrea maybe a little more info from logcat?

Comment: post your mainactivity class

Comment: In which event do you want to call your intent

Comment: In the event when user clicks on my time_button or date_button. and the buttons are found under one of my tabhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you may forget to add listener to your button

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_layout);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(yourId);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}
}
```

You must set one view to clicking listener

**Update:**

TabActivity is depricated. If you go to the Android developer guide they show you how this can be done

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

There is example code that shows you how to do this using fragments

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, but my MainActivity has already extends Tabactivity. How should I insert your code?

Comment: in which event do you need to call your intent